# Kentico 10 - Can I use multiple smart web parts on a single page?

Tags: kentico

Our Kentico website uses a Smart Search box web part on the header to perform a global search of content on the site.

I have a new use case now where we have a page that displays a bunch of products (which exist as page types). I just use a repeater on the page to display all the products using a simple transformation. We need a filter where the user can type into and it narrows down the list of products displayed but it has to be more than a simple name filter. It has to be able to narrow down the list based on some custom attributes that we added to the products and also keywords that can be entered into the page's properties.

I can make this work using a simple page name filter but this obviously only restricts the search to page names, which is not sufficient. I am aware that we can create custom filters that can possibly enhance this experience a bit further but before I started looking into that I thought I'd give the smart search a go.

I am using a Smart search dialog with results web part and I can get this to do exactly what I want but I am finding that when I type something into this search it also enters the same text on the other smart search sitting in the header. Although it doesnt actually perform the global search it does scroll the page to the top after the postback. This is certainly not ideal and the fact that the same search text is somehow also entered on the other smart search on the header simply won't fly.

My questions are:

- Is it "against the rules" to have multiple smart search web parts on a single page?
- What would be the correct or more acceptable way to satisfy my use case from a Kentico point of view? Should I be creating a custom filter for this purpose instead of a smart search (even though the smart search does exactly what I want up to a certain point)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not "against the rules" to have multiple smart search webparts on a single page.  Your master page should simply be a smart search box that redirects to a global search page with results.

The setup for your products should have it's own smart search index, several smart search filter webparts configured to work with a single smart search results webpart (not with a search box, just the results).  When configured properly, it will filter your results as expected.  You can use the textbox to search for content related items and use checkbox lists to perform a faceted search.

[Check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-search-filters) on faceted searching in Kentico.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. Also thanks for the link to the correct documentation. I didn't realise Smart search filter web parts could be used by themselves with a smart search results webpart. I thought they had to be paired with a smart search box or dialog to work.